# How do you stop Prettier in VS code splitting attributes onto multiple lines?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting, prettier

I am using prettier to format my code in VS Code but I really dislike how it does it.

My main beef is it splitting attributes over multiple lines.

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name="asiaNews"
    id="asiaNews"
    value="asiaNews"
/>
```

I'd much prefer it to look like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asiaNews" id="asiaNews" value="asiaNews" />
```

I can't find anything in the [docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) or on SO

[How to prevent VS Code from breaking up long HTML lines into multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112054/how-to-prevent-vs-code-from-breaking-up-long-html-lines-into-multiple-lines)

Is there a way to do it or a different tool that I can use so I can have my own custom formatting rules that suits my sensibilities?

Comment: I think it must have to do with your `printWidth` settings since it will only break your attributes into multiple lines if you're over the `printWidth` limit. You can test things out in the prettier playground: https://prettier.io/playground/

If you're over the `printWidth` I don't think there is anything you can do to prevent the attributes from going over multiple lines while using prettier.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

A quick fix is to go to Prettier Extension Settings (ctrl + shift + X) and in Prettier Extension Settings search for "Print Width" set it to 250 or anything that works for you.

**1: Go to Extention Settings:**

[image: Prettier Extension Settings]

**2: Change the value of Print Width to your liking.**

[image: Changing the value of Print Width]

To disable format code on save. Turn off the "Format On Save" and use `Alt+Shift+F` to format the code when ever you want.

[image: Disable or enable Format On Save]

You can visually check the setting [here](https://prettier.io/playground/)

Comment: But then the content of the html tag is also put on the same line?

Answer (score 36):

This happens because prettier assume that you want your code width to be in 80 characters only because of their default setting.

So You should tell prettier to I have too much space.

To do this simply create **.prettierrc.json** file in the root folder and add

```
{
 "printWidth": 600
}
```

And Save your file.
This will clear your issue.

Comment: The best solution mate!!!

Comment: This helps, but it should simply do an line break after the attributes pass the print width rather than force one attribute per line format.

Comment: This, indeed, is the solution that fixed this problem once and for all for me.

Comment: This should be the only answer on this page!

Comment: NOTE: After changing prettierrc, I had to restart VSCode for changes to take effect

Answer (score 15):

After Trying A lot, I came up with below solution.

1. Disable prettier for html files and use the default formatter
   provided by VS code.
2. Set the line length as per the requirements. (I
   set it to 100)

Here is my settings.json looks like after above changes.

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "html.format.wrapLineLength": 100,
  "prettier.disableLanguages": ["html"]
}
```

This will try to wrap the HTML attributes only if the length is greater than 100.
The good thing is that even if the length exceeds 100, it won't wrap each attribute to new line.

Answer (score 13):

Add this line to setting JSON to increase the maximuim line width,

```
  "prettier.printWidth": 160,
```

Answer (score 8):

`{"printWidth": 100}` in `prettierrc.json` is good enough.

Answer (score 8):

my solution was to **uninstall prettier** !! and install ESLint & typeScript extension. it comes with a basic formatter which does exactly what I wanted.
you can disable and enable them by search for formatter in settings

[image]

Comment: After trying everyting and being annoyed for literally months, this saved me! Thanks for posting this! :D

Answer (score 7):

You need to uncheck the box for "Prettier: Single Attribute Per Line"

[image: Prettier: Single Attribute Per Line]

Comment: I doubt this was the issue as [this feature was added in 2022](https://prettier.io/blog/2022/03/16/2.6.0.html) and this question is from 2019 and it is not enabled by default. However this is useful to know if you want the behavior that the OP does not. Note, however, that setting this value to false won't keep every attribute on one line (that's still controlled by the lineWidth property), but setting it to true will force every attribute onto a separate line.

Comment: This totally did not work.

Comment: @lewdev it did for me

Comment: This won't work!!! unchecking "Single Attributes Per Line" will only let them in one line IF line length <= `printWidth`!!!!

Answer (score 5):

add new rule in `.prettierrc.json` that located in your project:

```
{
    printWidth": 160,
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried the answers posted before and had no success.

Finally I found a solution for me by adding...

"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0

...to the setting.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```json
"singleAttributePerLine": true
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what OP wants!

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem as it worked for me:

```json
"prettier.singleAttributePerLine": false,
```

Answer (score -2):

all the answer is incorrect including the marked correct answer. the word wrap is not the problem. the problem is this line in your .vscode/settings.json or maybe global settings.json

"prettier.singleAttributePerLine": true,

This line will only allow one attribute in one line. That is why many people put 250 length wrap still not fixing the problem. simply change it to false and your jsx html will not break.

Comment: There is already an answer that suggests this.

Comment: This is so wrong!! And It's ironic suggesting this while saying everyone else is wrong. This is NOT why this option is for! Uncheck that while leaving line length <= printWidth won't solve anything!