# VSCode HTML attribute formatting

Tags: html, attributes, format, eslint, prettier

```html
<!-- As you can see, the element is broken into new lines, I saw this HTML style formatting somewhere but I dont know what it is called and how to turn it off. I am using VSCODE and have extensions such as Prettier installed. Thanks -->

<div 
  class="container"
 >
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<!-- My desired style: -->

<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

[enter image description here][1]

**I have ESLint and prettier installed, and I'm pretty sure these extensions cause this style formating that I don't like. HOw do I turn it off?**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzs5O.png

Comment: check if you have installed a new extension like HTML document formatter or prettier. remove it. Right-click and select the "Format with" you will see a list of document formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, prettier auto split your attribute base on `Print Width` property.

To change config please go to Prettier Extension Settings (ctrl + shift + X) and in Prettier Extension Settings search for "Print Width" set it to 250 or anything that works for you.

The answer for your question maybe here: [Is there a config in prettier to keep line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291245/how-do-you-stop-prettier-in-vs-code-splitting-attributes-onto-multiple-lines)

Comment: Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

Press (CRL + ,) and click (Edit in settings.json). Add the bellow line.

```
[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
},
```