# How do I disable "single attribute per line" function in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm a beginner web developer and I'm using VScode with Prettier extension. However, I disabled "single attribute per line" function of Prettier but while I'm writing HTML, somehow I still get only single attribute per line. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean to say it is getting chopped down right in several lines?

Comment: If this is the case you can use [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#) to customize your settings. Just change the language from the drop-down and see the result on the right window.

Comment: Yes, my attributes are getting chopped down in several lines.

Comment: Such questions are already asked by several folks. Do check this out you'll get many recommendations [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291245/how-do-you-stop-prettier-in-vs-code-splitting-attributes-onto-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > search for `singleAttributePerLine` in both User & Workspace tabs