# How do I prevent prettier from wrapping css rules

Tags: css, prettier

When prettiers wraps rules as the following

```
.SectionElementWrap.isDarkBookTheme
  .rootSectionElement:not(.isHighlighted):not(.View-ListDetail)
  .SectElIcon.SectionElement-viewOrPageIcon-white-path
  path {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87);
}
```

it gets harder to find such as rule in the code by the editor global search.
I was trying to find any settings but didn't find exactly for my need. Just found a certain `"html.format.wrapLineLength"` for html only as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291245/how-do-you-stop-prettier-in-vs-code-splitting-attributes-onto-multiple-lines) while the `"printWidth"` didn't help too.

Comment: How about using **[`/* prettier-ignore */`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html)**? Or if you want to ignore all your CSS files from prettier formatting, maintain a `.prettierignore` file and provide the glob.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I will do that at a last if there's no other way. thanks